what does this (h.hj=h.hj||function(){.....) syntax do?
Wanted to understand what does this below syntax do and what is it called.
h.hj=h.hj||function(){ (h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments) };
Wanted to understand what purpose does h.hj=h.hj serve before the OR condition.
Want to understand the purpose of the syntax and why its written that way.

This appears to be minified code, which is not designed to be easily ready by humans, it's designed to use lots of shortcuts/tricks/quirks of the language to make the code as short as possible.

@AndyRay TBH, only the identifiers are minified. Mentally replace h with AnalyticsLibrary, hj with track and q with queue...


Wanted to understand what does this below syntax do and what is it
called.
h.hj = h.hj || function(){ (h.hj.q = h.hj.q || []).push(arguments) };

It's a Javascript expression. It assigns a function to an hj property on an object named h.

Wanted to understand what purpose does h.hj = h.hj serve before the
OR condition.

h.hj = h.hj is regular assignment. If h.hj is truthy then h.hj is reassigned back to itself.

Want to understand the purpose of the syntax and why its written that
way.

This overall looks to be an expression to assign a singleton function to h.hj (whatever that is) that pushes arguments into an h.hj.q array each time it's called.
The first time this is called h.hj is likely undefined, so the function callback is assigned. On subsequent calls since this h.hj function is defined, i.e. truthy, it's simply reassigned back to itself.
In the callback an h.hj.q array is created if it does not exist, and on each function call an arguments variable is pushed into the array.

This pattern tends to be used for queueing calls for a library that may get loaded down the line, such as Google Analytics. When the library loads, it would then read h.hj.q and execute the calls as if h.hj was called directly.

Yes. The code is a part of hotjar analytics. Thank you btw.

@SanathShetty Well that seems to explain the hj variable name... or that's just an incredible coincidence.

I'll break it down for you...

h.hj=h.hj||function(){ (h.hj.q=h.hj.q||[]).push(arguments) };

h should be defined before this expression. It should be a function or an object.
h.hj = h.hj || function(){ ... } retains h.hj value if defined or, if undefined/falsy, defines it as function(){ ... }.
Inside the function, h.hj should be the function itself (if not defined anywhere else). h.hj.q retains h.hj.q value if defined or, if undefined/falsy, defines it as [].
Then the function just push the arguments given to the function into the h.hj.q which should be an array.
The main behavior here is that the function attaches every parameter given in its calls to the q property of the function itself. Then, later you can recover all those parameters through the function object itself.
